# Why custom tailwind font size is overwritten by text colour class

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Two custom tailwind classes are used `text-black` and `text-xxs`

`text-black` is just color `#000000`

`text-xxs` is a custom font size of : 10px

When used inside a cn util method:

```
// cn function
function cn(...inputs: ClassValue[]) {
  return twMerge(clsx(inputs));
}
```

Element gets only colour
`className={cn("text-xxs text-black")}`

**Output:** `text-black`

**Expected output:** `text-xss text-black`

*PS. Order of classes does not matter*

Comment: Since `cn` expects a list of arguments, shouldn't it be `className={cn("text-xxs", "text-black")}`?

Comment: There is no difference tbh.

idea is to have contant classes like that cn("...", true ? "" : "")
and conditionals or other types after that

it is still list of arguments